# IDA doesn't work inside screen

Tags: linux, ida

I am trying to run idal64 (IDA pro) inside a screen session, but I receive this error:

```
TVision error: Can not load libcurses.so
    Without libcurses can work only with xterm/linux
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I installed 'libncurses5-dev', 'libncursesw5-dev', 'lib32ncurses5-dev' and 'libx32ncurses5-dev', but nothing changed.

This library seems to be correctly installed:

```
#find / -name libcurses.so
/usr/lib32/libcurses.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurses.so
/lib/libcurses.so
/lib64/libcurses.so
/lib32/libcurses.so
```

My machine info:

```
Linux 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The weird thing is that IDA correctly works outside screen.
Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it's an 32bit / 64bit issue. Have you tried installing the `:i386` versions of the libraries? For example `libncurses5-dev:i386`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "outside screen"? What version of IDA are you using? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Odd. Confirmed this remains an issue with IDA 7.5 using `tmux`.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue running idal in tmux, and determined that

```
env TERM=xterm /path/to/idal
```

works around this issue for 32-bit idal.  Haven't tried idal64 but I expect this will work for you as well.